# let grep to search in multiple files in time order

Tags: grep

i have a directory with a lot of files like this,

[image]

if i use grep to seach a string in those files, then it will search by this order, file log.0, then log.1....

but i want grep to search base on time order, 
then i do like this,

```
grep -i 'stg_data.li51_cicmpdtap0521' 
$(ls -ltr sequencer_cmbcs_seq_debug.log*) | less
```

but i get this error

```
grep：invalid option -- -
```

after i change to this, it worked,

```
grep -i 'stg_data.li51_cicmpdtap0521' $(ls -tr 
sequencer_cmbcs_seq_debug.log*) | less
```

why ls -ltr do not work, but ls -tr work ? what's the difference between with -l and without -l here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `ls -ltr` does not work is because grep is trying to use the entire "long" output of the returned directory listing. Essentially what that equates to is something like this:

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user  staff    473 May 24 18:14 file
```

Which would give you a grep command like this:

```
grep -i 'string' -rw-rw-rw-  1 user  staff    473 May 24 18:14 file | less
```

Notice the dashes in the first column (example 1); grep can't interpret what to make of the input file and returns "invalid option". When you changed your `ls` command to remove the `-l` long output you now just have filenames and grep is able to proceed.